# Check if certain HTTP header was defined already

Tags: php, http-headers

For a WordPress plugin we need to add an `P3P` HTTP header to the output.

Now I need to check: If some other file already defined that header, we should not overwrite it (i.e. do not define it a second time)

Like this:

```
if ( ! header_defined('P3P') ) { // header_defined() is what I need to implement
    header( 'P3P:CP="..."' );
}
```

Comment: Use [`headers_list()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.headers-list.php).

Comment: I've never used it personally, but I think [`getHeader('P3P')`](http://php.net/manual/en/httpresponse.getheader.php) would be a better fit.

Comment: @HPierce: That looks to be part of a PECL extension though.

Comment: I think getHeader is not good, since it requires the PECL extension which is not included in php always...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [@Rocket Hazmat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/206403/rocket-hazmat) I could solve the problem and came up with this code:

```
$p3p_done = false;
foreach ( headers_list() as $header ) {
    if ( 0 === stripos( $header, 'P3P:' ) ) {
        $p3p_done = true;
        break;
    }
}
if ( ! $p3p_done ) { header( 'P3P:CP="NOI"' ); }
```

Comment: You may want to check `stripos() === 0` to only find the string at the start of the header, as this will return true for headers that contain `P3P:` anywhere, like `Foo-P3P:Bar`.

Comment: True. I thought that it's possible to send multiple headers in one line like `header( 'key:value; P3P:...' )` - but this actually declares the header "key" and not "P3P". Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: For fun: `$p3p_done = (bool)preg_grep('/^P3P:/', headers_list());`